# IDE for iPhone, iPad and desktop applications development on Mac

Tags: macos, ide

I am absolutely new to Mac world. Which IDE I can use for iPhone, iPad and desktop applications development?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332039/getting-started-with-iphone-development

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say [**Xcode**](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html).

To start using it, see, for example, [**Tools for iOS Development**](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/URL_Tools_for_iPhone_OS_Development/index.html).

And don't hesitate to take a look at the [**iPhone Dev Center**](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action) : it'll give you some useful informations about iPhone/iPad development ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is the IDE by which you make apps for iPhone,iPad and desktop..